# Postgres CHAR vs VARCHAR crossover variation

Tags: postgresql, database-design, varchar

In Postgres (or pretty much any SQL database, but I'm asking specifically about Postgres), if you know the content of the field will always be exactly 20 characters, it's obviously more efficient to make it CHAR than VARCHAR.

Suppose it varies somewhat. Not enormously, or it would obviously be better to use VARCHAR. Say the maximum is 20, but the average is about 10. In that case, is CHAR still more efficient?

In general, how much variation does there need to be, before it starts being more efficient to use VARCHAR?

Comment: Read the docs [Character Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html): The **Tip** section: *There is no performance difference among these three types, ... While character(n) has performance advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage in PostgreSQL; in fact character(n) is usually the slowest of the three because of its additional storage costs.*

Comment: There are more things you might consider such as concurrency, especially as this example scales up - if you use a fixed size for data that's not a fixed size then you are also using a fixed and largest-possible amount of memory per query, reducing the memory available for other concurrent queries. In addition the RDBMS knowing how much data is expected can influence the execution plan operation for a cost-based optimizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the column has always exactly 20 characters, `varchar(20)` won't be any less efficient than `char(20)` in PostgreSQL. Never use `char(n)`, because it has strange semantics, and you won't gain anything. See the "tip" in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html).